# Drupal Access Control and Civi Access

Tags: drupal, permissions

Question about Drupal access and Civi.  So I set up Civi permissions via Drupal Access Control and this works fine for the admin but any other roles I set up can't access Civi when the

Comment: as per in Slack can you pls explain a bit further. are you using Drupal Permissions? Did you mean CiviCRM Access Control?

Comment: So we have several roles - of course, one is admin which when you use the link to CiviCRM you are able to access without an issue. However, the other roles set up (there are 6) none will show the dashboard for Civi and say access is forbidden.  I started testing individual options and found when I added: {CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API

Master control for access to the main CiviCRM backend and API. Give to trusted roles only.}

I was able to access the dashboard for the user role I was logging in on.  It seems odd to me since this option indicate that it is for trusted users only.